# Ubuntu booting to maintenance mode after altering /etc/fstab

Tags: boot, partitioning, mount, fstab

I've got a file server running Ubuntu Server LTS 16.04.1.

Originally it had 2 hard drives, the first running my OS (swap and boot), the second was strictly a media storage drive (1 whole partition with ext4).

I've added a third drive and used parted to create the gpt disk parition table and set it to use the entire disk for an ext4 partition. That went okay.

I can see the disk and partition in /proc/partitions as well as the device for the disk and partition in /dev/sdc and /dev/sdc1.

The problem is the mounting. When I edit the /etc/fstab to include the third drive and reboot, the machine boots up to a maintenance prompt. When I change the /etc/fstab back to comment out the third drive, the machine boots normally. I feel like I'm missing something because my /etc/fstab should be working fine.

This is what I put in the /etc/fstab:

```
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/sda2 during installation
UUID=b4022d1c-ecc2-4902-ace7-f1a0c0e3ae1b /               ext4        errors=remount-ro 0       1
# /boot/efi was on /dev/sda1 during installation
UUID=055C-5059  /boot/efi       vfat    umask=0077      0       1
# swap was on /dev/sda3 during installation
UUID=6eedbf37-0c8c-45dc-abca-4361aba72045 none            swap    sw            0    0

#Secured Shared Memory
tmpfs   /run/shm    tmpfs   defaults,noexec,nosuid  0   0

#Secondard Drive
/dev/sdb    /mnt/Media  ext4    defaults    0   2

#Third Drive
/dev/sdc1   /mnt/MediaArchive   ext4    defaults    0   2
```

Comment: I see a problem with your second drive, should be sdb1, but you say it's your third drive causing problems...

Comment: Can you edit your post to include pictures of gparted for the 3 drives?

Answer (score 0):

So it turns out I was missing a step completely.

While I used parted to create the partitions, I was never actually formatting the partition. I was under the impression that parted did that for me when I created the partition and told it that I wanted an ext4 partition. This was not the case. I should have used:

```
sudo mkfs.ext4 /dev/sdc1
```

So my bad.

As for why you see my second drive referencing the sdb instead of sdb1, it's because during the installation of the server I didn't put a partition table on the second drive, instead I formatted the entire drive as ext4 without a partition table.

Sorry for the waste of everyones time.